# How to define terminating character for sql statement for DB2 using .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql, db2

I am tring to execute the following

```
 public void ExecuteNonQuery(string script) {
        try {
            int returnCode;

            var builder = new DB2ConnectionStringBuilder {
                                                             UserID = Context.Parameters["USERID"],
                                                             Password =Context.Parameters["PASSWORD"],
                                                             Database =  Context.Parameters["DATABASE"],
                CurrentSchema =  Context.Parameters["CURRENTSCHEMA"]
            };

            using (var connection = new DB2Connection(builder.ConnectionString)) {

                using (var command = new DB2Command(script, connection)
                    ) {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    connection.Open();

                    returnCode = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    File.WriteAllText(Context.Parameters["LOGFILE"], "Return Code -1 Successful : " + returnCode);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I am calling a script that has multiple statements ending in ;'s and at the end of the file it contains an @ symbol.  On a db2 command line I could use the db2 -td@ -f .  I would like to know how to define the @ symbol as the statement terminator so I could execute the script from csharp.
Here is example sql file :

```
DROP PROCEDURE fred@

CREATE PROCEDURE fred ( IN name, IN id )
specific fred
language sql
b1: begin
      update thetable
      set  thename = name
      where table_id = id;
end: b1
@

grant execute on procedure inst.fred to user dbuser@
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how we can define delimiters. But, you could try to split the whole text into individual statements in C# and then execute one statement after the other. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

That's an old question, but I had similar problem and here is the solution:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
create or replace procedure test
begin
  declare line varchar(100);
  set line = 'hello db2 world!';
  call dmbs_output.put_line(line);
end@
```

and then just:

```
$ db2 -f script.sql
```

and it will work fine.